# Cell information in GSM, UMTS, LTE

Tags: mobile, gsm, 3g, 4g

I'm trying to understand how a Mobile Station get the information about the cell from the BTS or the NodeB. The information I am looking for is :

```
Mobile Country Code (MCC)
Mobile Network Code (MNC)
Location Area Code (LAC)
Cell ID (CID)
```

What I have found is that the information about the cell is located in the Broadcast Control Channel (BCCH), at least for GSM. Am I wrong? What about 3G and 4G networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially right.Actually,The channel naming conventions will be slightly different when you look through the call flows in GSM,UMTS and LTE. The information related  to MCC,MNC will be transmitted through in the BBCH-DL-SCH channel.There are several type of SIB which get transmitted over the air and MCC and MNC will be covered as a part of SIB1.

The UE will latch into these channels and decode SIB to populate the parameters in the UE scope.

SIB 1 Parameters:
[image]

Google for BCCH-DL-SCH parameters/SIB information and you will find a detailed list of params.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you.